# Unresolved external symbol but the function is defined and implemented

Tags: c++, linker-errors, unresolved-external

I have a header file, defining the `chunk` class:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>

#include "Tile.h"
#include "Numerics.h"
namespace boch {
    class chunk {
    public:
        chunk();
        static const uint defsize_x = 16;
        static const uint defsize_y = 16;
        std::vector<std::vector<tile*>> tilespace;

        

        tile* getat(vint coords);
        void fillc(tile t);
    };
}
```

Then, I defined the implementation of the class in `Chunk.cpp` file:

```
#include "Chunk.h"

boch::chunk::chunk() {
    tilespace = std::vector<std::vector<tile*>>(defsize_x);
    for (int x = 0; x < defsize_x; x++) {
        std::vector<tile*> temp = std::vector<tile*>(defsize_y);
        tilespace[x] = temp;
    }
}

void boch::chunk::fillc(tile t) {
    for (int x = 0; x < defsize_x; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < defsize_y; y++) {
            tilespace[x][y] = new tile(t);
        }
    }
}

boch::tile* boch::chunk::getat(vint coords) {
    return tilespace[coords.x][coords.y];
}
```

(`vint` is a typedef of `boch::vector<int>` which is the custom X,Y vector, if that helps)

Then, I use it in the main function in `BochGrounds.cpp` file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Layer.h"
#include "Gamegrid.h"

int main()
{
    boch::layer newlayer = boch::layer(boch::vuint(16, 16));
    boch::chunk newchunk = boch::chunk();
    boch::gamegrid newgrid = boch::gamegrid();

    newchunk.fillc(boch::tile());
    newgrid.addchunk(boch::cv_zero, &newchunk);
    newgrid.drawtolayer(&newlayer);
    newlayer.draw(std::cout);
}
```

Tile class defines the gamegrid class, chunk includes tile class, gamegrid includes chunk & entity (which includes tile as well). Layer class includes only tile. All header files have `#pragma once` directive. When trying to compile, I'm getting the following error:

`LNK2019    unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl boch::chunk::chunk(void)" (??0chunk@boch@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function main`

`LNK2019    unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl boch::chunk::fillc(class boch::tile)" (?fillc@chunk@boch@@QEAAXVtile@2@@Z) referenced in function main`

and as the result:

`LNK1120 2 unresolved externals`

Other StackOverflow answers suggest that the linker cannot see implementations of both `fillc()` and chunk constructor functions, but I cannot see why if it is even the problem here. Please help. (Linker settings haven't been changed, and are default for MVSC 2019)

Comment: What commands do you use to compile and link the program?

Comment: Just to be clear: You've added both `Chunk.cpp` and `BochGrounds.cpp` are part of the same visual studio project and both files are actually built?

Comment: I'd verify again that `Chunk.cpp` is actually in the project and being compiled rather than just in the same directory as your other files. It's good practice to directly include the headers you use, so you'd want to include "Chunk.h" in `BochGrounds.cpp`. That's not the cause of your error but it will prevent things from breaking in a possible future where one of the other files doesn't include it.

Comment: @fabian yes both files are being built.

Comment: @RetiredNinja thanks for the advice! I've actually tried including every single header file, and it did not help sadly.

Comment: @NO_NAME I do not quite understand it, that is why I mentioned that I use MSVC 2019 defaults. I use no additional libraries, and use default g++ for compilation. If you would tell me where can I see the commands for the compiler, I would tell you!

Comment: @beriff I have no idea cause I don't use it but I suppose they may show in some log or other. If you use g++, look for lines that start with `g++` or `gcc`.

Comment: unresolved externals mean that there's no implementation found for symbols and basically mean you failed to add files in your project/solution. Double check that your cpp lies int proper `vsproj` file and it's included in your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks sugar for the answer. I deleted both header and .cpp files and readded them, and it worked like a charm. I suppose I have added either header or .cpp file just by directly adding a new file to the header/source folder instead of adding it to the project (RMB click on the project > add new item).